# How much health do the turrets and drill have?

Tags: awesomenauts

Since you can tell numerically how much damage you do per attack from the numbers that pop up above the enemy, how much total damage needs to be done to turrets and drills in order to destroy them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Patch 2.7 (released October 23, 2014), all damage and health numbers were multiplied by 10, to allow for more fine-tuning of damage numbers, which is why my numbers will be so different from the ones of the other answer currently present.

**The [Solar Drill](http://awesomenauts.gamepedia.com/Solar_Drill) always has 12,000 health**, but the amount of health a [Turret](http://awesomenauts.gamepedia.com/Turret) has varies between individual turrets. Generally, **a front turret will have 7,650 health, and a back turret will have 11,900 health**. Exceptions are as follows.

Sorona - front bottom: 5,300 health
AI Station 404 - front: 10,200 health
AI Station 404 - back bottom: 7,650 health

Note that unlike the health bars of 'Nauts, the health bars for turrets and drills always have 14 blocks when full, no matter what their max health is, so you can't figure out absolute values from that.

Answer (score 4):

According to [awesomenauts.wikia](http://awesomenauts.wikia.com/wiki/Awesomenauts_Wiki), [turrets](http://awesomenauts.wikia.com/wiki/Turret) have 1200 health and the [Solar Drill](http://awesomenauts.wikia.com/wiki/Solar_Drill) also have 1200 Health.